# Help in this definition of morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

I need help in this definition of morphism of affine algebraic sets which I found in a book:

Let $X$ and $Y$ affine algebraic sets and say

$$f:X\to X'\ \text{and}\ g:Y\to Y'$$

isomorphisms with $X'$ and $Y'$ affine closed sets.

A morphism $h:X\to Y$ correspond to a morphism:

$h':X'\to X\to Y\to Y'$

Where the map above are respectively $f^{-1}$, $h$ and $g$.

I didn't understand this definition, the author define $h$ using $h$?

I'm a little confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think what the author is saying is that if the composed map $h'$ is a morphism of affine closed sets (and presumably _that_ notion has already been defined) then we say that $h$ is a morphism of affine algebraic sets. I agree that it's a confusing definition.

Comment: btw what's the definition you know of morphism between affine algebraic sets? thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection between functions $h: X \rightarrow Y$ and functions $h': X'\rightarrow Y'$.

Given $h: X\rightarrow Y$, we can compose with the isomorphisms $f^{-1}$ and $g$ to get $g\circ h\circ f^{-1}: X'\rightarrow Y'$.

Conversely, given $h': X'\rightarrow Y'$, we can compose with the isomorphisms $f$ and $g^{-1}$ to get $g^{-1}\circ h'\circ f: X \rightarrow Y$.

$$\begin{array}
XX & \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} & Y \\
\updownarrow{f} & & \updownarrow{g} \\
X' & \stackrel{h'}{\longrightarrow} & Y'  
\end{array}
$$

Presumably you already know what a morphism of affine closed sets is (a function which is polynomial in coordinates). The author is declaring that a function $h': X' \rightarrow Y'$ is a called a morphism (of algebraic sets) if and only if the corresponding function $h: X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism (of closed sets).

Comment: The author didn't say that $h$ is a function.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're reading?

Comment: Of course I can, but unfortunately it's not in english, that's why I didn't say the name of the book in the question.

Comment: But the book is based on Shafarevich's book

Comment: Alright then. The point is that the author must have said what a morphism of affine closed sets is before giving this definition - if he didn't, it doesn't make any sense. Moreover, he must have said what he means by an isomorphism between an affine closed set and an affine algebraic set.  At this level (algebraic geometry prior to the introduction of schemes), morphisms really are functions. If the author didn't mean for a morphism of affine algebraic sets to be a function, he wouldn't be able to give the definition he does, which relies on you knowing how to compose $h'$ with $f$ and $g$.

Comment: That's my confusion, because I've already studied a little bit of the theory of schemes and morphisms at this level are not necessarily functions as you said.